# AppCenter installation options

Tags: appcenter

Whats the difference between "AppCenter", "AppCenter (System-wide)" and "elementary Updates"?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elementary OS distributes some software as [Flatpaks](https://www.flatpak.org/), and some as [Debian packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/pkg-basics.en.html).

Debian packages provide the core system libraries and software, like the kernel, command line utilities, and graphical applications that haven't yet been updated to the newer and more secure Flatpak format.

elementary has recently been working on moving their software to the Flatpak format as well, which is why you see "AppCenter" or "AppCenter (system-wide)" showing up for software in AppCenter.

Long story short:

- "AppCenter" means an app is a Flatpak installed for your user only
- "AppCenter (system-wide)" means an app is a Flatpak installed for all users on your system (think Music or Camera or Web)
- "elementary Updates" refers to system libraries/software installed via Debian packages (the kernel, bash, systemd, etc)

If you want to greatly increase the software selection in AppCenter, you can also add the [Flathub remote](https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS/), which will make even more software available in the Flatpak format.